# Is there any possibility to vectorize this?

Tags: python, numpy

Currently I'm working on a project that implements cubic spline interpolation. So far I have managed to calculate coefficients for my equations. 
Now I'm trying to return an interpolating function that for any x returns y.

Let's assume that we have

```
x = [1, 3, 5]  
y = [6, -2, 4]
```

The coefficients that we get are as follow:

```
[ 6, -5.75, 0, 0.4375, -2, -0.5, 2.625, -0.4375]
```

It is equal to

```
[ a<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>0</sub>, c<sub>0</sub>, d<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>, d<sub>1</sub>]
```

The interpolating polynomials are

```
S<sub>0</sub>(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>0</sub>*x + c<sub>0</sub>*x<sup>2</sup> + d<sub>0</sub>*x<sup>3</sup> x ∈ [1, 3]  
S<sub>1</sub>(x) = a<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>1</sub>*x + c<sub>1</sub>*x<sup>2</sup> + d<sub>1</sub>*x<sup>3</sup> x ∈ (3, 5]
```

And so on - it can be calculated for more than only 3 points

Right now I have implemented a method that works only if one x is given as an input.

```
def interpolate_spline(x, x_array, coefficients):
    i = 1
    while x_array[i] < x:
        i += 1
    i = i - 1

    a = coefficients[4 * i]
    b = coefficients[4 * i + 1]
    c = coefficients[4 * i + 2]
    d = coefficients[4 * i + 3]

    return a + b * x + c * (x ** 2) + d * (x ** 3)
```

And coming back to my question: Is there any possibility that it can be vectorized or at least take whole array as an input?
I don't know if that matters but assume that x_array is sorted

Comment: I would look into scipy's interpolation capabilities. Coding these types of things from scratch is probably not superior or useful unless you're doing it for learning purposes

Comment: Surely scipy interpolation would do its job, but I'm trying to implement it just for learning purposes :)